# How do you call the element of position X in an numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np

S = np.array(l)
for i in range(1, l):
    random_int = randint(0, 1)
    np.append(S, random_int)
```

I create a numpy array of size l and and fill it with zeros and ones. Let's say I want to print the third element of the array. How do I do that?

If I type

```
print(S[2])
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply do in this way to generate L random numbers between 0 and 1:

```
L = 10
S = np.random.random_integers(0,1,L)
print S
print S[2]
```

returns:

```
[1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1]
0
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

`np.append(S, random_int)` appends `random_int` to a **copy** of the array `S`. You need to use `S = np.append(S, random_int)` in your `for` loop.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint

l = 5
S = np.array(l)
for i in range(1, l):
    random_int = randint(0, 1)
    S = np.append(S, random_int)

print(S)
print(S[2])
```

**Output**

```
[5 1 1 0 1]
1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `S = np.array(l)` does not result in an array of length l, but with a length 1 array whose only entry is l.
So you can replace this line with `S = np.zeros(l)` (creating an array of length l full of zeros.
Then, in your for loop, you must do:

```
for i in range l:
   S[i] = randint(0, 1)
```

This is just to point out your mistakes. As @Fabio said, you can do this in one line.

Comment: Thank you, I just started using numpy so things like that trick me easily.